# Group records for hourly count

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

My goal is to build an hourly count for records that have a start date/time and an end date/time.  The actual records are never more than 24 hours from start to finish but many times are less.  It works if I bounce every record against my "clock" which has 24 slots for every date up to "today".  But it can take forever to run as there can be 2000 records in a day.

This is the detail I get:

[image]

The date/times in green are what I want as the start date/time for a group.  The blue date/times are what I want as the end date time for the group.

Like this:

[image]

I have tried partitioning but because, in the second pic, the 4th row has the same values as the 2nd row, it groups them together even though there is a time span between them - the third row.

Comment: replace images with plain text fragments

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Thank you for the plain text fragments tip.  This being my first post I was not sure if anyone would see my pics.   I did some very convoluted stuff before posting my question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  The start and end dates match on adjacent rows, so a difference of row numbers seems sufficient:

```
select id, min(startdatetime), max(enddatetime),
       d_id, class, location
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by startdatetime) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by id, d_id, class, location) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
group by id, d_id, class, location, (seqnum - seqnum_2);
order by id, min(startdatetime);
```